# bound on expectation of a two-variable function under an independent distribution

Tags: expected-value, sample, central-limit-theorem, approximation, probability-inequalities

Consider a probability distribution $P(x)$, a set observed samples $S = \{x_1,\cdots, x_n\}$ where $x_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} P(x)$ for $i \leq n$, and a symmetric function $h(x,y)$.

How can one efficiently approximate $E_{xy}[h(x,y)] = \sum_x\sum_y P(x)P(y) h(x,y)$ using the observed set $S$ when $P(x)$ is unknown and the $h(x,y)$ function is given?

I also would like to find a tight bound indicating that with the high probability $p$ the approximated value is $\epsilon$-close to the true expectation value. The higher $p$ is and the smaller $\epsilon$ is, the tighter the bound is.

Comment: Several aspects of this situation are still unclear. Presumably the $x_i$ are independent, right? Do you know $P$ or is that supposed to be estimated from $S$?  Do you know $h$ or its expectation, or are you given some values of $h(x_i,x_j)$ obtained from $S$, or do you have some other information about $h$?

Comment: Yes, $x_i$ are independent. We don't know P; it is supposed to be estimated from $S$. We know the exact definition of function $h$. I will incorporate these clarifications in my question; thanks for point out about them.